# How should I instantiate my state from props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Reading [around](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html), I see that initializing state from props in the getInitialState()/constructor can be an anti-pattern.

What is the best way of initializing state from props and managing to be consistent?

As you can see below, I'm trying to initialize my "Card" component so that I may have a *likeCount* and *isLikedByMe* states initialized. I do this so that I may have a custom like counter displayed and the text of the Like button to change, by resetting the state.

At this point, I'm doing this in the constructor, but that is the wrong way to do it. How should I manage this?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { CardLikeButton } from "./buttons";

export enum CardType {
    None = 0,
    Text,
    Image
}

export interface CardMedia {
    text?: string;
    imageUrl?: string;
}

export interface CardDetails {
    isLikedByMe: boolean;
    likeCount: number;
}


export interface CardParams extends React.Props<any> {
    cardType: number;
    cardId: string;
    cardMedia: CardMedia;
    cardDetails: CardDetails;
}

export class Card extends React.Component<CardParams, CardDetails> {

    state: CardDetails;

    constructor(props: CardParams) {
        super(props);

        console.log("in card constructor");
        console.log("card type: " + props.cardType);

        this.state = { // setting state from props in getInitialState is not good practice
            isLikedByMe: props.cardDetails.isLikedByMe,
            likeCount: props.cardDetails.likeCount
        };

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: CardParams) {
        this.setState({
            isLikedByMe: nextProps.cardDetails.isLikedByMe,
            likeCount: nextProps.cardDetails.likeCount
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log("RENDERING CARD");
        // console.dir(this.props.cardDetails);
        // console.dir(this.props.cardMedia);
        // console.dir(this.props.cardType);

        if (this.props.cardType === CardType.Text) { // status card
            return (
                <div className="general-card">
                    <p>Text card.ID: {this.props.cardId}</p>
                    <p>{this.props.cardMedia.text}</p>
                    <CardLikeButton onButClick={this.likeButtonClicked} buttonText={this.state.isLikedByMe ? "Liked" : "Like"} isPressed={this.state.isLikedByMe}/>
                    <p>Like count: {this.state.likeCount}</p>
                </div>
            );
        } else { //photo card
            return (
                <div className="general-card">
                    <p>Image card.ID: {this.props.cardId}</p>
                    <p> {this.props.cardMedia.text} </p>
                    <img src={this.props.cardMedia.imageUrl} />
                    <br/>
                    <CardLikeButton onButClick={this.likeButtonClicked} buttonText={this.state.isLikedByMe ? "Liked" : "Like"} isPressed={this.state.isLikedByMe}/>
                    <p>Like count: {this.state.likeCount}</p>

                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    likeButtonClicked = () => {
        console.log('in card => like button clicked!');
        var _isLikedByMe = this.state.isLikedByMe;
        var _likeCount = this.state.likeCount;

        if (_isLikedByMe) {
            _likeCount--;
        } else {
            _likeCount++;
        }
        _isLikedByMe = !_isLikedByMe;

        this.setState({
            isLikedByMe: _isLikedByMe,
            likeCount: _likeCount
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the main list component:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />

import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import {Card} from "./card";

import {CardParams, CardType, CardMedia, CardDetails} from "./card";

var card1: CardParams = {
    cardType: CardType.Image,
    cardId: "card1234",
    cardDetails: {
        isLikedByMe: false,
        likeCount: 3
    },
    cardMedia: {
        text: "some test text; badescuga",
        imageUrl: "http://www9.gsp.ro/usr/thumbs/thumb_924_x_600/2016/06/19/738742-rkx1568-lucian-sinmartean.jpg"
    }
};

var card2: CardParams = {
    cardId: "card35335",
    cardType: CardType.Text,
    cardDetails: {
        isLikedByMe: true,
        likeCount: 1
    },
    cardMedia: {
        text: "some test 2 text"
    }
};

var cards = [card1, card2];

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>

        {
            cards.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <Card key={item.cardId} cardId={item.cardId} cardType={item.cardType} cardDetails={item.cardDetails} cardMedia={item.cardMedia}/>
                );
            })
        }
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("mainContainer")
);
```

Comment: Are you using a state container like Redux?

Comment: where are the initial props coming from?

Comment: @Mark no, i'm not! i'm a beginner and am trying to get the best practices on working with react. Is there a way to manage this without the help of redux?

Comment: @omerts i have a main component that renders a list of cards. I'm updating the code to reflect the main component

Comment: Have you checked flux architecture? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/flux-overview.html

Comment: You can instantiate your state with props inside componentWillMount() method.

Comment: @Ved this is the very first thing i'm doing after. I though that i should start with react to be able to understand each 'best practices' separately, and not have them confused.

Comment: I will suggest you go through flux tutorila and react component life cycle.https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: Also have a look to this example: https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc

Comment: You are correct, what your doing is an anti pattern and not worth the effort of trying to get it to work in this way. React is a view rendering framework and works best when used with an architectural pattern such as Flux so you are really best off learning these two in parallel IMO

Comment: @Ved i actually read the docs bad, i understood that i won't render the state changes at all (on the first render) if i use componentWillMount. I think that's what i needed!

Comment: Alex, if you fell any difficulty further, fell free to ask. I will be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into working with Flux, or Redux, and focusing on your question.

IMHO, state and props need to be separated, where `Card` only gets props, and state is managed from above. `Card` component will get an event handler to raise once the like button has been clicked. You could either do the "like" logic inside the `Card` component, and just raise the event handler with the output of that logic, for example:
 `this.props.likeClicked(isLikedByMe, updatedLikeCount)`.
Or, do the whole logic in the parent component.
I would also wrap all cards in another component.

Example:

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: CardParams) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
      return (  
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.likeButtonClicked}>
            {this.props.isLikedByMe ? 'Unlike' : 'Like'}
          </button>
          <p>Like count: {this.props.likeCount}</p>
        </div>
      )
   }

    likeButtonClicked = () => {
        console.log('in card => like button clicked!');
        var _isLikedByMe = this.props.isLikedByMe;
        var _likeCount = this.props.likeCount;

        if (_isLikedByMe) {
            _likeCount--;
        } else {
            _likeCount++;
        }

        _isLikedByMe = !_isLikedByMe;

        if (this.props.likeUpdated) {
          this.props.likeUpdated({
            cardId: this.props.cardId,
            isLikedByMe: _isLikedByMe,
            likeCount: _likeCount
          })
        }
    }
}

class CardList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) 

    this.state = {
                    // Could use es6 map
                    cards: {123: {isLikedByMe: false, likeCount: 3},
                            124: {isLikedByMe: true, likeCount: 2}}
                  }
  }

  _onLikeUpdated({cardId, isLikedByMe, likeCount}) {    
    const cards = Object.assign({}, this.state.cards)
    cards[cardId] = {isLikedByMe, likeCount}

    this.setState({cards})
  }

  _getCards() {
    return Object.keys(this.state.cards).map(cardId => {
      return <Card key={cardId}
                   cardId={cardId} 
                   likeUpdated={this._onLikeUpdated.bind(this)}   
                   {...this.state.cards[cardId]} />
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
            {this._getCards()}
           </div>
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/do13ez79/